# Connection between the database system and a browser

Tags: sql, database, jsp, browser, system

I want to create a database system then upload this system to any browser. .. I'm really beginner in this area and I want to know what tools should I use and what is the best program to use in order to implement it ?? after I implement it I should put it in a server and it should have a specific IP address

Comment: When you ask a question and you get an answer, please mark it explicitly as an answer. That will improve your rate and give points to the one who helped you.

Comment: @MevoHafez Can you edit your question with the details you are providing in the comments so that you get more helpful answers. Also it would be great if you can explain your requirement in detail. Thanks

Comment: I did that thank you for your comment .. The requirement is that I should implement a database system and this system should be in a browser, my question is that what is the best program to do that and what I should download in order to begin working with this system

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood ...
you want:

1) a client that gathers data

2) store this data in a local database

3) upload this data to a database located on a server.

there are several ways to do this:

1) upload the database file manually using a simple webform and read the database file on the server. (this might raise problems when you have inconsistent data ...)

2) read the database file with a client program and upload the data only to e.g. a REST API. (same problem of inconsistent data)

3) skip the local database part and just submit directly to the server.
(most common way of storing data on a server)

Comment: doesn't matter. Any language can achieve this.
Note.. JSP is not a program, rather a framework for Java.. which is a programming language. I know I'm argueing symantics here, but just to keeps things clear for everyone.

You can write this in Java, PHP, C#.. depending on your infrastructure.
Do you have a linux host with mySQL? Then I wouldd go for PHP.
Do you have Windows hosting? Then I'd choose C#.

Comment: How can I write it in java .. what program can I use to do that coz I hear that I only can implement it using HTML, javascript and stuff like that .. I prefer to implement it using java it will be much easier than other coz I know this language

Comment: I can't write it for you ...
take a look at JSF or JSP :)